# Convert DXF file to RasterLayer

Tags: raster, r, dxf, rgdal

I am an R user and have a .dwg file of city buildings that I wish to transform into a RasterLayer using the heights as elevation data.

The metadata for the DXF file states:

```
DXF File Metadata: Projection - MTM 3 Degree Zone 10 NAD27, WGS84 Latitude/Longitude
```

What is the recommended workflow to do this? I am on a Mac if that is helpful.

Since .dwg is proprietary I converted it to .dxf using ODAFileConverter.app

Still, it's not clear to me as to how to read the file.

Is there geolocation type data in the DXF file? Can that become part of the RasterLayer?

QGIS 3.6 crashes if I try Project > Import/Export > Import Layers from DWG/DXF with the DWG file. If I try the DXF file it just creates a single line. I know the file is good because I can view it OK with Autodesk's Online [Viewer](https://viewer.autodesk.com/).

```
library(rgdal)
file = "50G_SOUTH2.dxf"
ogrListLayers(file)

[1] "entities"
attr(,"driver")
[1] "DXF"
attr(,"nlayers")
[1] 1
```

```
ogrInfo(file)
Error in ogrInfo(file) : Multiple # dimensions: 2:3
```

35 MB DWG file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sczfm61jui7zlve/50G_SOUTH2.dwg?dl=0)

278MB DXF file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d9dwdmm97s10tf0/50G_SOUTH2.dxf?dl=0)

Comment: Try reading it with the `sf` package? `sf::st_read("filename.dxf")` - because `sf` objects are better at handling multiple dimensions (at a guess I suspect the data contains points, lines, and polygons)

Comment: No go. Error in st_sfc(NextMethod(), crs = st_crs(x), precision = st_precision(x)) : 
  found multiple dimensions: XY XYZ

Comment: Ah yes its an extra dimension as well as multiple geometry types... If I can make a file with multiple dims I'll have a go (can't really d/l 278MB at the moment).